# User Registration - Incorrect Logic

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

I'm having multiple issues with my code. I have wrote a user registration form with validation, however I need help on what I would write for it to be saved in the database and if I'm missing anything. As of  right now, it is not working. When I click register, it just refreshes the page.

I appreciate any help, thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript"> 

                function validateRegistrationForm(){
            if(!validateEmailField()) // Invalid email format
            return false;
            if(!validatePasswordField()) // Invalid password length
            return false;
            if(validateUserNameField()) // invalide characters in email
        return false;
}

            function validateEmailField(){
            var x=document.getElementById("email").value;
            var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
            var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
            if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
{
            errorPopup("Not a valid e-mail address");
            return false;
}
    if(email==x) //If the old email is equal to the current then perform no check for uniqueness. On the server side the email portion will be ignored.
        return true;

    return isEmailUnique(); // return true if the email is unique
}
</script>


</head>

<body class="nobg loginPage">

    <header>
    </header>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="ic"></div>
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="container_12">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="grid_12">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="grid_12">
                        <h2 class="h-pad1">Open an Account with Us</h2>
                        <form action="" id="validate" class="form" method="POST">
            <fieldset>
                <div class="formRow">
                    <label for="login">Username:</label>
                    <div class="loginInput"><input type="text" name="username" class="validate[required]" id="username" maxlength="15"/></div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="formRow">
                    <label for="pass">Password:</label>
                    <div class="loginInput"><input type="password" name="password" class="validate[required]" id="pass" /></div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="formRow">
                    <label for="pass">Repeat Password:</label>
                    <div class="loginInput"><input type="password" name="rpassword" class="validate[required]" id="rpass" /></div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="formRow">
                    <label for="pass">Email:</label>
                    <div class="loginInput"><input type="text" name="email" class="validate[required]" id="email" /></div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="formRow5">
                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6Lfz39kSAAAAABY7fpEs0x1ZzvcFSP-gClbe8XYb"></script>
                <noscript>
                <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6Lfz39kSAAAAABY7fpEs0x1ZzvcFSP-gClbe8XYb" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br/>
                <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
                <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge"/>
                </noscript> </div>
                <div class="loginControl">
                    <input type="submit" value="Register" class="dblueB logMeIn" name="registerBtn"/>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>          
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: in your validateEmailField you reference `if (email==x)` but as far as I can see the email variable is never defined. the `isEmailUnique()` function does not appear to be defined. the `errorPopup()` function does not appear to be defined. your `validateRegistrationForm()` function seems to return false or undefined no matter what - it never returns true, and also I don't see anything that calls this function? the `validateUsernameField()` and `validatePasswordField()` functions appear not to be defined. You have a Form element with a submit button and a POST method, but no action URL.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell - you don't have anything linking the submission of the form, to the validation code you've written. Is your `validateRegistrationForm()` function even being called when you submit the form?

As for your function - you'll want to return `true` if the form elements are valid, and `false` if they are not. returning `false` will cancel submission of the form.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, you can't use JavaScript to write to a database as JS is client-side code and the database tends to be on a server. In that case you'll need to use a server-side language to do so (like .NET, PHP, Java, etc.). You might be able to get a more detailed answer if you can say what database you want to write to and what server language you are using (if you are using any already).

Comment: I just want a simple user registration form, when users sign up, they can login.

Comment: That means you need some way of keeping track of their details, which means you (almost definitely) need a database, which means you (almost definitely) need some server side code. I would suggest the simplest method (based on my own personal preference) to be PHP, but it will depend on some factors, like where your site is being hosted, what access (if any) you have to install software on that server computer and/or what software is already installed on it.

Comment: As Chris said, it'll depend on where your site is hosted, but a number of web hosts allow you to use MySQL and PHP. There are a lot of resources that can be found online for using PHP to write to a MySQL database if you're unsure of how to use the two.

Answer (score 0):

Before you click the register button, there's a javascript error...

Line 14 column 1: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . "